# Samba credentials changing when attempting to mount

Tags: networking, samba, fstab

I'm trying to mount Samba shares automatically using fstab.

Right now my fstab entry for the network share is

```
//bistack/matt  /mnt/Network_Shares/Matt  cifs  user=matt,pass=*****,auto,nouser,exec,rw,async,atime,vers=3.0  0  0
```

Although when I try to mount the shares using `sudo mount -av` it errors out with error 13 permission denied. I thought this was simply because the password or the username I had was wrong, although the verbose output has the credentials as `user=root,pass=********` which is of course not the same as the fstab file has.

Comment: Did you put your credentials in `smbpasswd` ?

Comment: Yes, the credentials work. I can log in to the web interface using the same ones.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the web interface does not use `smbpasswd`, and being able to login there does not mean your credentials are valid with Samba.  A bit complex to explain in this comment, but do this: Please edit your question, and include the output of `testparm` (incl the service definitions) run on your samba server host.